Is the Virial Theorem dependent on the classical Equipartition Theorem?
The Wikipedia entry for the Virial Theorem states:

"*The significance of the virial theorem is that it allows the average total kinetic energy to be calculated even for very complicated systems ... this average total kinetic energy is related to the temperature of the system by the equipartition theorem*."

Was it not shown that the classical equipartition theorem is not compatible with actual observations for black body radiation which calls into question its validity and in turn would appear to call into question the validity of the Virial Theorem, if that theorem assumes the validity of the equipartition theorem in its derivation? Is the modern derivation of the Virial Theorem independent of the discredited Equipartition Theorem or do I have it wrong and the Equipartition Theorem is not discredited?

The next sentence from the wikipedia article answer your question

That sentence only says the Virial Theorem does not depend on the notion of temperature, but does that make it independent the Equipartition Theorem which is about degrees of freedom and not necessarily tied to temperature?

The equipartion theorem is about systems in thermal equilibrium (and so temperature). The viral theorem does not depend on thermal equillibrium

These theorems hold for systems in classical mechanics that obey certain assumptions. Equipartition theorem does not hold in quantum theory. But quantum variant of the virial theorem does hold in quantum theory.

The equipartition theorem is definitely not discredited. Simply, there are conditions for its validity, and its application to black body radiation certainly goes beyond these limits of validity.
In the following, I'll try to separate the roles played by classical and quantum virial theorems on one side and the equipartition theorem in classical Statistical Mechanics on the other.
As illustrated with all the details in the Wikipedia page on the Virial Theorem, both in classical and quantum mechanics, there is a result named Virial Theorem, linking the time average (classical case) or the expectation value (quantum case) of a quantity named Virial ( $\sum_k{\bf r}_k\cdot {\bf F}_k$ ) to the time average (classical case) or the expectation value (quantum case) of the total kinetic energy.
Generally, it holds independent of the possible existence of a thermal equilibrium in the system. For example, the virial theorem is routinely used
in the study of the stellar motion in galaxies, and a galaxy is not a system at thermal equilibrium.
In the case of equilibrium Classical Statistical Mechanics, it is possible to prove a related result:
$$
\left\langle x_i \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_k}  \right\rangle = \delta_{ik}k_BT. \tag{1}
$$
Where the set of the $x_i$'s is the set of all the Hamiltonian coordinates and momenta.
If $x_i = x_k =p_i$, we have the usual equipartition theorem
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N\left\langle p_i \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}  \right\rangle =  2 \left\langle T \right\rangle= Nk_BT\tag{2}.
$$
($T$ being the total kinetic energy).
If $x_i = x_k =q_i$, and using equation ($2$), we recover the same result of the Virial Theorem for a classical equilibrium system.
The step not allowed in the case of a quantum system or a classical system not at thermal equilibrium is to identify the average kinetic energy with temperature.
